# logstash grok filter annoyance

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

`Thu Sep 27 15:30:27 BST 2012:- Invalid token $_POST[custom], which indicates the amount, userid`

This is from a log file I'm trying to parse using grok for logstash.

The first few fields are ok, and it seemed very close to DATESTAMP_OTHER, but I think that the UK timezone of BST is messing that up.

Got as far as this, but not sure how to make it work!

`%{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %([PMCEB][SD]T) %{YEAR} %{GREEDYDATA:message}`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1) Try out the [Grok Debugger](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) which will allow you to test your Grok patterns, on the spot.

2) Also, change your `%([PMCEB][SD]T)` for something like `(?<variable_name>(BST)*)` to start off with. You are using the wrong syntax for plain regex.

3) **Most important** Read the [docs](http://logstash.net/docs/1.1.12/filters/grok). Everything I have just mentioned came directly from the docs.

Comment: OMG the Grok Debugger is amazing. A life saver!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach to the problem:

```
TZEXPANDED (?:[PMCEB][SD]T) MYCUSTOM %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{TZEXPANDED} %{YEAR}
```

Or if you prefer:

```
MYCUSTOM %{DAY} %{MONTH} %{MONTHDAY} %{TIME} %{(?:[PMCEB][SD]T)} %{YEAR}
```

In my opinion, the first option is better, because you can use the pattern later on for something else

Greetings